# Example of a function for which the axiom of choice is needed to prove that it has a right-inverse

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice, inverse-function

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function. We define a right-inverse of $f$ as a function $g$ satisfying $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y$ in the range of $f$. Using the axiom of choice, it is can be proven that every function has a right-inverse:

> Let $S=\{f^{-1}(\{y\}):y\in\operatorname{ran}(f)\}$. Let $\phi:S\to\bigcup S$ be a choice function such that $\phi(A)\in A$ for each $A\in S$. Let $g(y)=\phi\bigl(f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigr)$ for all $y$ in the range of $f$. This function is a right-inverse of $f$.

Of course, the axiom of choice is not always necessary to define such a function $g$. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, then the function $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is an explicit example of a right-inverse of $f$. Is there an easy example of a function where we *do* need to invoke the axiom of choice to prove that it has a right-inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Consider map from infinite sequences of real numbers to countable sets of reals given by mapping a sequence to the set of reals appearing in the sequence.

Clearly, this is a surjection, and an inverse function would allow you to uniformly choose an enumeration for each countable set of reals. However, without choice it is consistent that there is no such inverse.

Indeed, if there is such inverse, then there is a set which is not Lebesgue measurable, and there is a set without the Baire property.

---

Similarly, one can replace this by mapping the sequence to an ordinal $\alpha$ if the sequence's range is order isomorphic to $\alpha$ (under the standard order of the reals), or to $0$ if it isn't well ordered at all. An inverse function here would imply there is an injection from $\omega_1$ into the reals, which consistently does not exist without assuming choice.

Comment: Hi Asaf. Thanks for this answer. Since I am a first-year undergraduate student, I did not fully understand what you wrote. However, I *think* I understood the first part: is my modification of your argument correct?

Comment: Let $A$ equal the set of functions $f$ from $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$, and let $B$ equal the collection of countable subsets of the reals. Define the function $\Phi:A\to B$ by
$$
\Phi(f)=\operatorname{ran}(f) \, .
$$
for every $f\in A$. Now, suppose that there is a function $\tau:B\to A$ for which $\Phi(\tau(b))=b$ for all $b\in B$. Then, there would be a function which associates to each countable subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$, a function $f$ from $\mathbb N$ to $X$.

Comment: This would give us a well-ordering of $X$—for each $x\in X$, let $p(x)$ be the smallest natural number $a$ such that $f(a)=x$. Then, we can say that $x<y$ if $p(x)<p(y)$ (in the usual ordering of the naturals). However, without the axiom of choice, we cannot say that every countable subset of $\mathbb R$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: Not quite. If a set is countable, then it can be well-ordered pretty much by definition. The point is that from an inverse to $\Phi$ we can well-order every countable set of reals *uniformly*, i.e. at the same time.